# How to disable strictNullChecks in spec test files in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

In my *tsconfig.json* I have rule `"strictNullChecks": true` but I don't want this in my tests which is all *.spec.ts files. So I was trying to override this flag in my *tsconfig.spec.json* but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "downlevelIteration": true,
        "importHelpers": true,
        "module": "esnext",
        "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "alwaysStrict": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types"
        ],
        "lib": [
            "es2017",
            "dom"
        ],
        "baseUrl": "./ClientApp",
    },
    "angularCompilerOptions": {
        "strictTemplates": true,
        "strictOutputEventTypes": false
    }
}
```

tsconfig.spec.json

```
{
    "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "../out-tsc/spec",
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "target": "es5",
        "types": [
            "jasmine",
            "node"
        ],
        "strictNullChecks": false
    },
    "files": [
        "test.ts",
        "polyfills.ts"
    ],
    "include": [
        "**/*.spec.ts",
        "**/*.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

Comment: How do you understand override does not work? Do you observe compilation error or it is just an IDE's one (and if it is IDE's what IDE do you use)?

Comment: My IDE Visual Studio Code highlight the line and saying that I have an error there.`Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Router'.ts(2345)`

Answer (score 2):

Both [VS Code](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/12463) and [WebStorm](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/12463) look for the nearest to the opened file `tsconfig.json` for a configuration to be used for IDE TS support. They do not know about Angular's specific files such as `tsconfig.app.json` and `tsconfig.spec.json`. 
So the bad news is that it seems impossible to have support for different sets of preferences only depending on the file extension. The separation can be done only on folders level what means you need to put all the tests in one folder and the app code into another one.

The good news is that using angular-cli everything should compile correctly.

As a workaround, it is possible to use assertions

```
const y: string = null as any;
```

Or a bit safer way that allows tracking error after changing signatures shows error:

```
function f(dep: string) () { }
const x = f(null as any); // Ok

// And it won't notify you after changing the type of function argument
// what can be desirable in some cases
function f(dep: number) () { } 
const x = f(null as any as number); // Ok and will show error for incorrect type
```